# В коде программ на каких языках программирования есть возможность делать вставки на языке программирования C?

Tags: c, любой-язык

В каких языках можно делать вставки на языке C прямо в коде программы? Именно чистый Си интересует, не C++.

Comment: https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/interoperability/c-with-rust.html

Comment: @КириллМалышев,  что-то я не увидел сишного кода, вставленного в rust по вашей ссылке.

Comment: С++? (шутка -))

Comment: @avp, так я и не обещал ничего вам

Comment: если именно "вставки", то тут avp прав - это с++, хотя и не поддерживает на 100% все возможности си. Если же слово вставки трактовать шире, то это любой язык, который поддерживает подгрузку dll/so или просто написан на си/с++ (тут список сразу стает сильно-сильно побольше).

Comment: Я знаю С++ и Cython.

Comment: Именно текстовые вставки.